# Django Rest Framework - URL Queries Not Working?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am writting an application in Django that uses the Django Rest framework. A GET request to the API URL works, but when I add a query to it, such as '?id=1845' it does not actually perform a query, it still returns the full list of results.

In the below code, I am trying to query the 'Indicator List'

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import IndicatorSerializer

from data_platform.models import Indicator

@api_view(['GET'])
def apiOverview(request):
    api_urls = {
        'Indicator List':'/indicator-list/',
        'Indicator Detail':'/indicator-detail/<str:pk>/',
    }
    return Response(api_urls)

@api_view(['GET'])
def indicatorList(request):
    indicators = Indicator.objects.all()
    serializer = IndicatorSerializer(indicators, many=True)
    #filterset_fields = ('id')
    #filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def indicatorDetail(request, pk):
    indicators = Indicator.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = IndicatorSerializer(indicators, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.apiOverview, name="api-overview"),
    path('indicator-list/', views.indicatorList, name="indicator-list"),
    path('indicator-detail/<str:pk>/', views.indicatorDetail, name="indicator-detail"),
]
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from data_platform.models import Indicator

class IndicatorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Indicator
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to pass the id as a queryString ``` '?id=1845'``` you should just add it at the end of your URL like ```/indicator-detail/id```

Comment: This is the URL I have been trying: http://localhost:8000/api/indicator-list/?id=1845  - I also tried http://localhost:8000/api/indicator-list/id=1845

Comment: Try localhost:8000/api/indicator-list/1845 without specifying the id keyword but also make sure the view for listing all Indicators supports listing a single indicator otherwise you will have to use indicator detail view which means the URL will change to localhost:8000/api/indicator-detail/1845

Comment: In addition, the detailed URL doesn't need to have that ending slash, I would set it as ```indicator-detail/<str:pk>``` instead of ```indicator-detail/<str:pk>/```

Comment: Tried all that, does not work

Comment: According to your view, you should only use the indicator-detail URL to get a single indicator returned in the response. But did you add a custom id field to the model? If not in the detail URL you should set it to int not str

Comment: I'm confused... I can't query a list? What do I need to do so that I can?

Comment: Since you want to fetch a single indicator instance, you should use indicator detail. what  meant was, you cant do it using the indicator list view because you didn't write codes to filter them by id's in the indicator list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I had to use a class view rather then a function view

```
class indicatorList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = Indicator.objects.all()   
serializer_class = IndicatorSerializer
filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]
filter_fields = ('id',)
```

and add 'django_filters', to INSTALLED_APPS